# How to add project to tomcat server in intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've been able to configure my tomcat server in Intellij and have been able to run the server successfully. However, I can't seem to find where to actually add my project to the server in intellij. I'm used to using eclipse where I would right-click my server and use the "Add and Remove" feature for the server. Is there something similar in intellij?

Comment: I've tried to add my project in the server config setting under the deployment tab but now when I run the server, I'm getting a 404

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can find the configuration page of server, 
And add a new tomcat server,
and then set the webapp home as you need in the new server,
At last, the new server is the server you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a web Facet at `File - Project Structure`
2. Create an Artifact from this Facet at the same page
3. Add a tomcat run configuration at `Run - Edit configurationes`, go to the Deployment tab, add you artifact to `Deploy at the server startup`